# Consistent positioning of <table> element across modern browsers

Tags: css, html

I have two `<table>` elements, and I want to arrange them vertically in a specific way by making the second `<table>` shift horizontally by a fixed amount of pixels.

For example:

```
<table id="table1" align="center">
    ...
</table>
<table id="table2" style="padding-left: 130px;">
    ...
</table>
```

However, I've found that in different browsers (e.g. Chrome vs Safari) the `padding-left` attribute causes slightly different results (i.e. while the second table appears fine in one browser, it is 2 or 3 pixels off the desired result in another browser). Is there any way to make this positioning consistent across all modern browsers? Preferably, a CSS-only solution is better.

Comment: To center with css use `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:70%;` (Or whatever percent you want) but note that 100% does not center. - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a CSS reset on `padding` and `margin`, browsers have default values for these, and the values are not the same across all browsers. The default values could be interfering your expected behavior.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

More on CSS reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/